# How to dynamically create properties in polymer as needed

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have a use case where I have a component (like a database) that I would like to expose all the information as bindable properties.  However, only a few of those properties will be need by any particular client who uses it.  There could be 1000's of entries in the database.  How can I figure out which ones are actually needed by the client.

For example:

```
Polymer('database, 
    {
       observer : {
           name : function(oldVal, newVal) { onDataChanged('name', newVal);},
           addr : function(oldVal, newVal) { onDataChanged('addr', newVal);},
           tel.main : function(oldVal, newVal) { onDataChanged('tel.main',
                 etc....
        }
    });
```

In this case I would like to dynamically create observe handlers only for the data bindings that are actually needed on the fly.

Comment: This does not answer your question but, I think when building elements using polymer you should have a `-` in the name of your element.

Comment: Please change _'database_ to _'database'_

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to have your clients extend your component to specify the desired database fields then you can dynamically create observers only for the fields they specify.

## Example

### Component

```
<link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name=demo-dynamicproperties >
 <template>
   <h2>dynamic properties</h2>
   See the console for changes
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
   // Validate that it is an attribute that is allowed
   //  For the example we will allow anything starting with validitem
   isValidAttribute: function(name) {
     return (name.match('^validitem'));
   },
   // Get attributes
   created: function() {
     for (name in this.publish) {
       console.log("Trying: "+name);
     // Verify that it is one of the dynamic attributes
     if (this.isValidAttribute(name)) {
         console.log("Accepting: "+name);
         this[name]="Pull from DB";
         // References:
         // https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/node_bind.html
         // https://github.com/Polymer/NodeBind/blob/master/tests/tests.js
         // https://github.com/polymer/observe-js
         var observer = new PathObserver(this,name);
         observer.open(makeHandler(this,name));

     }
    }
     /************* TEST **********************************/
         // Verify that dynamic updates worked by updating
         this.job('update_validitem1', function() {
           this.validitem1="Updated after 10 seconds";
         }, 10000);
     /************ End Test ******************************/

   }
  });
  // Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
  function makeHandler(element, property) {
    function handler(newval,oldval) {
       console.log("element" + element,"property:" + property,"from:"+oldval,"to:"+newval);
    }
    return handler;
  }
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

### Usage

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="../../webcomponents/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="demo-dynamicproperties.html">
  <title>demo-dynamicproperties test page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<polymer-element name=demo-usedb extends="demo-dynamicproperties" attributes="validitem1 validitem2 invaliditem" noscript>
</polymer-element>
  <h1>Demo</h1>
   <template is="auto-binding">
    <h2>Dynamic tag</h2>
     <demo-usedb validitem1="{{item1choice2}}" item2="setthis"></demo-usedb>
    <h2>Input</h2>
      <input type="text" value="{{item1choice2}}">
    <h3>Produces</h3>
     {{item1choice2}}
  </template>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However, this is what I was trying to avoid.  Having to specify the same information twice.  Anytime you do that you open yourself up for programmer error, and make it less user friendly.

Comment: The best I was able to do without having it specified in two locations was: Client data binding changed -> db element attribute -> db element code seeing change.  But the reverse was only element changing -> db element attribute changed.   With the client data binding  not see the update.    If the client -> db element is the only direction you need I can provide that code but it seemed like an incomplete solution.  It used the attributeChanged callback to detect changes and only select on attributes I cared about.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer to the questions is that it cannot be done.  There does not appear to be any hooks or events that a component can use to get notified when properties are bound (or attempted to be bound) to it.  I filed a bug/enhancement request here 
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1303

to request that this feature be supported in the future.